# How do I remove this Artifact

Tags: swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle to document my API.  When I open the swagger page, I get this item highlighted in the image.  How do I get rid of it or replace it?  Using v5 of the swashbuckle tooling

[image: Strangley Formatted version of my route.]

Comment: Can you provide sample code of your swashbuckle configuration and any other relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Here are the section.

Startup.cs - Services

```
// Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v0",
                Title = "LTK Manager",
                Description = "Sample Description",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
            });

            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
            c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();

        });
```

Startup.cs - Configuration

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v0/swagger.json", "LTK Manager V0 (alpha)");
            c.DisplayOperationId();

        });
```

Route Decoration

```
      /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a parameter store value from an account/region
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Awesomeness!</remarks>
    /// <response code="200">Returns an Object Containing the response from the API.</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getParamStoreValue")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public IActionResult getKey([FromBody] ParamStoreRequest req)
```